# Azure Blob Storage get only child directory in location using Powershell

Tags: list, azure, powershell, directory, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to only get the child directories in a specific directory location in and Azure Blob container using Powershell.

I am using `Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $container -Blob "backup/11-1-0/backup/*"` but this lists all sub-directories in my blob location.

This is the directory structure in my blob container:

```
  backup/11-1-0/backup
    20230713-100023-BACKUP
      data
        abf7bdde-aa2b
      services
        20230713-100023-BACKUP-services.bu
      files
        20230713-100023-BACKUP-files.bu
    20230714-100023-BACKUP
      data
        4bf1-9eb1-51
      services
        20230714-100023-BACKUP-services.bu
      files
        20230714-100023-BACKUP-files.bu
    20230715-100023-BACKUP
      data
        eb1-51449671f68c
      services
        20230715-100023-BACKUP-services.bu
      files
        20230715-100023-BACKUP-files.bu
```

When I list the directories in `backup/11-1-0/backup/*` I want to just see `20230713-100023-BACKUP`, `20230714-100023-BACKUP` and `20230715-100023-BACKUP`.

Ultimately I want to check the date of the backups' main directory and delete it if it is older than 7 days.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

This is the directory structure in my blob container:

```hs
 backup/11-1-0/backup
   20230713-100023-BACKUP
     data
      12-07-2023.html 
     services
      10-07-2023.html 
     files
       11-07-2023 (1).html
   20230714-100023-BACKUP
     data
      sprite.html
     services
      results (1).csv
     files
     03-07-2023.html
   20230715-100023-BACKUP
     data
     20230711071825.csv  
     services
      23-06-2023.html
     files
      09-06-2023.html
```

> When I list the directories in `backup/11-1-0/backup/*` I want to just see `20230713-100023-BACKUP`, `20230714-100023-BACKUP` and`20230715-100023-BACKUP`.

If you need to get these folders `20230713-100023-BACKUP`, `20230714-100023-BACKUP` and`20230715-100023-BACKUP`` you can use the below command.

**Command:**

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "venkat123" -StorageAccountKey "accountkey"
$container = "test"
$prefix = "backup/11-1-0/backup/"

$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $container -Prefix $prefix
$directories = @{}
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    $directory = $blob.Name.Substring(0,$blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/'))
    $parentDirectory = $directory.Substring(0,$directory.LastIndexOf('/'))
    if ($directories.ContainsKey($parentDirectory)) {
        continue
    }
    $directories[$parentDirectory] = $true
    $parentDirectory.Substring($parentDirectory.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
}
```

**Output:**

```
20230713-100023-BACKUP
20230714-100023-BACKUP
20230715-100023-BACKUP
```

[image]

> Ultimately I want to check the date of the backups' main directory and delete it if it is older than 7 days.

To check and remove the files older than 7 days you can use the below command.

**Command:**

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "venkat123" -StorageAccountKey "your-account-key"
$container = "test"
$prefix = "backup/11-1-0/backup/"

$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $container -Prefix $prefix
$directories = @{}
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    $directory = $blob.Name.Substring(0,$blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/'))
    $parentDirectory = $directory.Substring(0,$directory.LastIndexOf('/'))
    if ($directories.ContainsKey($parentDirectory)) {
        continue
    }
    $directories[$parentDirectory] = $true
    $parentDirectoryName = $parentDirectory.Substring($parentDirectory.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
    $parentDirectoryDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($parentDirectoryName, "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-'BACKUP'", $null)
    $daysOld = (Get-Date) - $parentDirectoryDate
    if ($daysOld.Days -gt 7) {
        Remove-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $container -Blob $parentDirectory -Force
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

[Work with blob containers from PowerShell - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-containers-powershell)